# <Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle): Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds> R Package SLGA

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to use the `SLGA` package to find the sand content of soils in Australia.

I am behind a firewall at work and so previously could not install the package from github, but now can download from the CRAN repository.

Unfortunately though, I am unable to use the functions to call data possibly because of the firewall.

I tried to use some example functions from github and another question on here and get the timeout for all of them.

Looking at other similar questions looks like it's a proxy/firewall/DNS issue but I'm not really sure what to do as I don't have admin privileges on my machine.

I may be able to request through my IT team that the required URLs are not blocked but I'm not sure exactly which I should ask for-

http://www.clw.csiro.au/aclep/soilandlandscapegrid/
or
http://www.asris.csiro.au/arcgis/rest/services/TERN
or
others?

Any ideas how I can do this @obrl_soil?

```
aoi <- c(152.95, -27.55, 153.07, -27.45)

bne_surface_clay <- get_soils_data(product = 'NAT', attribute = 'CLY', 
                                   component = 'ALL', depth = 1, aoi = aoi,
                                   write_out = FALSE)
```

Error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
>     Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds

Comment: It's difficult to debug local system or network issues for other people. You should talk with local IT support to resolve this problem. If the issue is a proxy, a common solution (for Windows) is to add the proxy URL and port to the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

Comment: @neilfws I had seen something about the .Renviron file before but couldn't find it. Just realised I could create it! 

I typed: 

file.edit('~/.Renviron')

In Rstudio and that created the file.

I found out what the proxy URL is and added it to those variables in the .Renviron file. It worked! Thank you thank you

Comment: Good to hear! Then I'll add it as an answer and you can upvote/accept if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen similar issues at my workplace. A proxy is often the issue and a common solution is to add appropriate environment variables.

For example if the proxy URL is `proxy.abc.xyz` on port 80, you can define:

```
HTTP_PROXY=proxy.abc.xyz:80
HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.abc.xyz:80
```

This can be in a `.Renviron` file. Or on Windows 10, you can open "edit the system environment variables" in Control Panel.